# Find highest number and increment by 1

Tags: javascript

I have created a small script that creates a folder with a unique id, i.e. ABCD01.

The ABCD is based on the input name and the number is based on how many matches there are for the 4 digit code i.e. If have 3 folders all with the the code ABCD, the next number would be 04 as it’s counted 3 matches already.

This script works but I found an issue. If I have folders ABCD01, ABCD02, ABCD03 and I delete ABCD02, the next number would be ABCD03 as it can only count 2 instances of ABCD. I now have 2 ABCD03’s which will cause an issue.

Is it possible to take the highest number and increment its by 1?

Here’s my code

```
console.log("there's no match");
let RemoveSpecials = BaseName.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, ""); // ABCCompanyThe
let FourDigitCode = RemoveSpecials.slice(0,4); // ABCC  
let UpperCaseCode = FourDigitCode.toUpperCase(); // ABCC  
let code = (' (') // (
let newcode = code.concat(UpperCaseCode); // (ABCC  
let CompiledName = BaseName.concat(newcode); // ABC Company, The (ABCC
console.log(CompiledName);

let list = ["ABC Company, The (ABCD01)"];
console.log(list);

let AlreadyExist = fmCloud.listContents(strPath).filter(hhh => hhh.includes(newcode)).length;
    this.number = this.number || AlreadyExist;
    this.number++;
    let Num = ('' + this.number);
    if(('' + Num).length == 1) {
        Num = '0' + Num;
    }
    let CompiledNamhghge = BaseName.concat(newcode + Num + ')'); // ABC Company, The (ABCC
```

I have tried using something like the following but doesn’t work.

```
const foo = ["Company Name (COMP01)", "Company Name, The (COMP02)", "Computer Name, The (COMP03)"]

let lastNumber = Math.max(foo);
let nextNumber = parseInt(lastNumber)+1;
console.log (nextNumber)
```

Comment: `Math.max(foo)` - `foo` is an array of strings. How is this supposed to work? o.O

Comment: You should do some parsing on the directory names to get that number before applying `Math.max` on it.

Comment: Match the numbers in `(COMPXX)` (`.match()`), convert them into actual numbers (`parseInt()`), find the maximum (`Math.max()`) and add `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const foo = [
  'Company Name (COMP01)',
  'Company Name, The (COMP02)',
  'Computer Name, The (COMP03)'
];

const numFromString = str => str.match(/\d+/)[0];

let lastNumber = Math.max(...foo.map(f => numFromString(f)));

let nextNumber = lastNumber + 1;
console.log(nextNumber);
```

Comment: (Or just `foo.map(numFromString)`)

Comment: this code would break on `21st Century Fox (COMP123)` , try using `/(\d+)\)$/` instead

Answer (score 1):

```js
let lastNumber = Math.max.apply(null,foo.map(function(name){return Number(name.match(/(\d+)\)$/)[1]);}));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and I can confirm it works. Rather than just take ‘3’, how do I take ‘03’? I’m worried when it gets to ‘10’, will I then have the number ‘010’?

Comment: @Juan-man that shouldn't happen, i used Number() to trim away the leading zeroes.. but if you want the 03 instead, maybe something like ```let lastNumber = (function(){
let highestNum = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
let highestVal= null;
for(let i in foo){
   let currentNum = Number(foo[i].match(/(\d+)\)$/)[1]);
   if(currentNum > highestNum){
      highestNum=currentNum;
      highestVal=foo[i].match(/(\d+)\)$/)[1];
   }
}
return highestVal;
})();```

Comment: Thanks that has worked a treat, I have an issue with this code though in adding a number  let nextNumber = lastNumber + 1; gives me the number 031? It worked in your last code giving me 4

Comment: @Juan-man `"03"` is a string, `Number("03")` is a number; if you try to use the `+` operator on a string, it will append to the string, if you try to use the `+` operator on a number, it will increase the number; `"03" + 1` is indeed `"031"` , and `Number("031") + 1` is 4; if you need something to increment the number in strings like `"03"`, then write a specialized increment function, there's nothing built-in to javascript to increment such strings.